# Writing to a session variable with SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, session

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I'm performing a `GET` request on a method inside a controller that needs to read a value stored in session. To avoid session state locking issue, I've set `SessionStateBehavior` to `ReadOnly` on the class level.

```
 [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
    public class TestController: Controller
    {
         var test = Session["KEY"];
...
```

However, very occasionally, I need to overwrite the `Session` variable to something else inside that same method. ASP.NET MVC does not allow me to do this with `SessionStateBehavior` set to `ReadOnly`. I can't set it to `Required` because then I run into the issue of session state locking issue again, preventing concurrent AJAX requests.

What's a good solution for this?

Edit: We're using SQL server for session state management.

Comment: Does the modificaition of the session is based on a condition?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes

Comment: So you can create another Controller with required session. When the condition to,the session is true in your TestController then redirect to the action of the newly created controller.

Comment: Due to business requirements, that's not exactly a feasible solution. We have about 100 controllers being called from the front-end that we'd need to rewrite the frontend code for. I'm looking for a solution that can be handled entirely on the backend.

Comment: So maybe Session is not the answer for stoging the user data. Create a memory cache per user and make sure the access to that memory is thread safe.

Comment: We're using sql server for session management (multiple web servers in a web farm). Doesn't feel like that's also a good option...

Comment: Indeed. You are totally right ;-)

Comment: Have you tried a [LockLess](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/single-asp-net-client-makes-concurrent-requests-writeable-session-variables/) or an [Async](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/29/introducing-the-asp-net-async-sessionstate-module/) Session-State Store Provider? Wouldn't it be a possible solution for you?

Comment: If the modification of the session is based on a condition then can you redirect to another Action that has the `SessionStateBehavior` set to `Required` when you need to change to the `Session` variable. This way you can minimize unnecessary locks if that's viable under your circumstances. Of course you'd have to evaluate the cost of a Redirect/Transfer.

Comment: @l46kok did you give a try with `RoutHandler` . `IRouteHandler` has one method - `GetHttpHandler`. When you make a request to a controller, by default the routing engine handles the request by creating a new instance of `MvcRouteHandler`, which returns an `MvcHandler`.  `MvcHandler` is an implementation of IHttpHandler which utilises IRequiresSessionState interface. Here is a [blog Explaining](https://web.archive.org/web/20090814023401/http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/) this implementation

Answer (score 4):

If you target .NET Framework 4.6.2 and you're on SQL Server, you could leverage the new [async SessionState module](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/29/introducing-the-asp-net-async-sessionstate-module/) to access the session storage providers asynchronously.

Download and install the SessionStateModule and the [SqlSessionState](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync/) NuGet packages.

Consider also that [SQLServer mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx) stores session state in the SQL Server database.

**Note (from the comments)**

While the session in ASP.NET Core is non-locking, only next release of `SqlSessionStateProviderAsync` should introduce this feature, according to this [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/29/introducing-the-asp-net-async-sessionstate-module/#comment-126705).

### Alternative provider

Another, different option would be to use [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/): e.g. for a web app in Azure App Service, follow these [configuration steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-web-app-howto#configure-the-application-to-use-stackexchangeredis).
More generally, in a Redis server or servers, [RedisSessionProvider](https://github.com/welegan/RedisSessionProvider) never locks the Session

Comment: This solution just enables the asynchronous access to the session state. It does not fundamentally resolve our issue, as the problem of preventing concurrent access to SessionState still exists due to the exclusive lock placed on the sessionstate.

Comment: Maybe you can mitigate an excessive amount of locks by [*caching the async values*](https://giuliohome.wordpress.com/2016/12/31/caching-async-method-results) with a relatively short time expiration...

Comment: But that doesn't fundamentally resolve my needs, and we're already caching our results as much as we could.

Comment: In that case, **afaik** you should consider either an upgrade to ASP.NET Core ("*the session in asp.net Core is non-locking*") or next release of `SqlSessionStateProviderAsync`, according to this [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/09/29/introducing-the-asp-net-async-sessionstate-module/#comment-126705)

Answer (score 2):

create a customControllerFactory which inherit with `DefaultControllerFactory`, and override the `GetControllerSessionBehavior()`. then use `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory()` to register the factory at Application_Start

see http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/session-state-behavior-per-action-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: @DávidMolnár althrough it is internal, i can override it and correctly executed. .net 4.6.2 debug info: [https://postimg.org/image/mhzytehlr/](https://postimg.org/image/mhzytehlr/)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using a SQL Server session backend, I think you can achieve what you want by manually interacting with the session database and bending it to your will.

Familiarize yourself with the [workings of a session provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx), in particular the [`SqlSessionStateStore`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/sqlstateclientmanager.cs) class. Under the hood, all it's doing is (de)serializing your data and calling the stored procedures in the session state database (specifically, check out [`SetAndReleaseItemExclusive`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/sqlstateclientmanager.cs,620)).

If you can figure out how to construct a [`SessionStateStoreData`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/ISessionStateStore.cs,128) object, or more specifically the [`ISessionStateItemCollection`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/SessionStateItemCollection.cs,24) needed to construct it, from the session collection you have access to via the `HttpContext` plus whatever changes you want to make, you can then use reflection to call the internal static [`SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/State/SessionStateUtil.cs,188) method. After that, it should be trivial to call the correct stored procedure (based on the updated session's size).

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically set the session state behavior for every request. Based on some condition you can switch to `SessionStateBehavior.Required` and in any other case just use the default behavior.

You will need a custom MvcRouteHandler:

```
public class MyMvcRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override SessionStateBehavior GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            return SessionStateBehavior.Required;
        }
        // fallback to default behavior
        return base.GetSessionStateBehavior(requestContext);
    }
}
```

In the `requestContext` you will find `HttpContext` and based on that you can decide what to do.

You will need to set this new `RouteHandler` for every necessary route. You can do this in the `RouteConfig` file, put this after route registrations:

```
// ...
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
// ...

// set MyMvcRouteHandler for every route
foreach (var route in routes.OfType<Route>())
{
    route.RouteHandler = new MyMvcRouteHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a logic issue and two opposite business requirements which are: the readOnly and the need to modify that given some conditions.
So, what i would do is to go back to your logic and cover the conditions.
I would use the ***Set method*** SetSessionStateBehavior() to sort of toggle.
For example, add a simple if statement as follows (sudo code)

```
    If a condition is met that requires non readOnly then
     SetSessionStateBehavior(
    SessionStateBehavior required
 )
```

// here do what you need to do then set it back

Answer (score 0):

You can try Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync 1.1.0 version which supports concurrent requests with same sessionid. Here are the steps to use that nupkg. (you can find more details about the package on [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/aspnet-2-preview-1/))

1. install SqlSessionStateProviderAsync 1.1.0
2. add appsetting  to web.config